# String Object to Array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

Wonder, I get from some API the following string:

```
parseresponse({"eurusd":{ "id": "eurusd", "category": "Forex", "price": 1.3161, "name": "EUR/USD", "buy": 1.3162, "sell": 1.3159, "change": 0.00, "date":1328288216000}});
```

for some reason I can't replace it to Array when I using:

```
var_dump(json_decode($content));
```

and I trying with php function also:

```
function object2array($object) {
if (is_object($object)) foreach ($object as $key => $value) $array[$key] = $value;
    else $array = $object;
return $array;
}
```

any idea?..

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to parse `JSONP` response as `JSON`, you should remove wrapping function first.

```
$response = 'parseresponse({"eurusd":{ "id": "eurusd", "category": "Forex", "price": 1.3161, "name": "EUR/USD", "buy": 1.3162, "sell": 1.3159, "change": 0.00, "date":1328288216000}});';
$json = preg_replace('/^parseresponse\((.*)\);/', '$1', $response);
$data = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: That's strange, if your input matching the sample you provided it output should be correct. If not just tune regex for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$content = '{"eurusd":{ "id": "eurusd", "category": "Forex", "price": 1.3161, "name": "EUR/USD", "buy": 1.3162, "sell": 1.3159, "change": 0.00, "date":1328288216000}}';

function toArray($data) {
    if (is_object($data)) $data = get_object_vars($data);
    return is_array($data) ? array_map(__FUNCTION__, $data) : $data;
    }

$newData = toArray (json_decode($content));

print_r($newData);
```

output will be:

Array
(
    [eurusd] => Array
        (
            [id] => eurusd
            [category] => Forex
            [price] => 1.3161
            [name] => EUR/USD
            [buy] => 1.3162
            [sell] => 1.3159
            [change] => 0
            [date] => 1328288216000
        )

)